# Ordering writeline outputs from text file using C# in console

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console.writeline

I wonder if you could help me at all. Essentially my program has to scan through a text file and then print the lines. Each line that is printed must be alphabetized also, if possible. I could do with being able to point at any file through cmd rather than automatically pointing it at a specific file and in a specific location.

I have this so far as I wanted to get things working in a basic form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Program
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String line;
        try
        {
            //We Have to pass the file path and packages.txt filename to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\packages.txt");

            //Instruction to read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Further Instruction is to to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                //Instruction to write the line to console window
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //The read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //Finally close the file
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I hope you guys can help me, I am very rusty!

My thoughts were to convert the string into an char array? then modify and sort using array.sort method.

OK guys. On your advice I have made a few changes. I get an exception thrown at me now as we are trying to get it to accept an argument in order for us to point it at any text file, not a specific one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Program
{
class Program
{
    static void Main (params string[] args)
    {
        string PathToFile = args[1];
        string TargetPackages = args[2];

        try

        {

            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(PathToFile);
            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in textLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(TargetPackages))
                {
                    results.Add(line);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(results);
            }
        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you mean with "alphabetized" that each character in a line is sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I mean actually that each line is separated by a double whitespace. The structure of each sentence is word -> word . So I essentially need to ensure that the first word is the one it sorts alphabetically.

Comment: do you need also to output it in the same manner?  : "dorw -> word"

Comment: I guess it would be best to give an example. Say there were three lines first being dog -> word second line cat -> word third line Mouse -> word       What the output should be is three lines but in in alphabetical order (by the first word i.e. cat then dog then mouse

Comment: ok after this new information I edited my post. May be this time it is more fitting to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort by the first word and output, you need to read all the lines into memory (I hope your file isn't too large), sort the lines, and then write them back out.

There are many ways to do all that. The [File class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) has some helper functions that make reading and writing text files line-by-line very simple, and LINQ's [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) method makes quick work of sorting things.

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    outputFileName,
    File.ReadLines(inputFileName).OrderBy(line => line));
```

See [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on how they work.

If you want to load each line, sort the first word, and then re-output the line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    outputFileName,
    File.ReadLines(inputFileName)
        .Select(line =>
            {
                var splits = line.Split(new [] {' '}};
                var firstWord = new string(splits[0].OrderBy(c => c));
                var newLine = firstWord + line.Substring(firstWord.Length);
                return newLine;
            }));
```

Note that this loads and processes one line at a time, so you don't have to hold the entire file in memory.

Comment: Thank you. You have all been so helpful, I shall give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

You should be better off by reading all lines at once and then looking at each line separately, like this:

```
List<string> allLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(pathToFile).ToList();
allLines = allLines.OrderBy(line => line).ToList(); //this orders alphabetically all your lines
foreach (string line in allLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

This will print all the lines in the file ordered alphabetically.

You can also parametrize the path by using the args parameter you receive when opening the application:

```
CMD> pathToYourExe.exe path1 path2 path3
```

You can mock this by using the DEBUG arguments in the project's Debug menu

Comment: Really guys thank you very much for helping! I just wondered if I was ok to ask. Your method, am I right that the sorting output is working for each letter only, whereas I believe I need this to work for each line. How easy is this to alter?

Comment: @LordFlashheart your question is not very clear. Please edit your question and add a sample input and the expected output so we can help you better.

Comment: @LordFlashheart please see my edit where the first code block contains what you want to achieve